# loop an array, then put values back into elements on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I am looking to loop through all the elements with a data-speed attribute and record them. Then loop back though that array on resize to put them back to original values.

I am able to get my data-speed attributes of all elements that contain that data attribute and log them. But now I need to record them, and then add those data-attributes back to the original elements at the original value (in my resize function). Below is my html, along with how I have the JS setup so far:

```js
 // get all data-speed numbers and log them

    const el = document.querySelector('.smootherReset768');
    var dataAttribute = el.getAttribute('data-speed');

    $('.smootherReset768[data-speed]').each(function(){
      console.log($(this).data('speed'))
    });

    //put the values into my resize function
    $(window).resize(function (){

    var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 768px)" );

    if (mq.matches) {
        // I can change all data-speed attributes here easily
    }
    else {
        // add code to return each element to it's original data-speed
    }
    
    }).resize();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div class="col-2 smootherReset768" data-speed=".8"><img  src="https://assets.codepen.io/181080/home-3-900x900.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="col-2  smootherReset768" data-speed="1.2"><img  src="https://assets.codepen.io/181080/home-2-900x900.jpg"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the job:

```js
const el = $('.smootherReset768'),
  factors = [.001, .002], // arbitrary factors for smaller windows --> use GSAP instead!!
  speeds = el.map((i, e) => $(e).data('speed')).get(); // collect original values

// assign speeds according to window size:
$(window).resize(function() {
  const smallWin = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches
  el.each((i, e) => $(e).data("speed",
    smallWin ? factors[i] * window.innerWidth  // small window: calculated speeds
             : speeds[i]));                    // large window: original speeds
  console.log(smallWin, el.map((i, e) => $(e).data("speed")).get().join(","))
}).resize()
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-2 smootherReset768" data-speed=".8"><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/181080/home-3-900x900.jpg" /></div>
<div class="col-2 smootherReset768" data-speed="1.2"><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/181080/home-2-900x900.jpg" /></div>
```

Basically, everything you do here you can do in Vanilla JavaScript too. But, as you have chosen to work with jQuery you should do it consisently and avoid methods like `document.querySeletor()` and `document.getAttribute()`.

Another point worth noticing might be that the callback functions for `jQuery.each()` and `jQuery.map()` require their arguments: `(index, element)` in the reverse order of the corresponding `Array.prototype` functions of JavaScript (the order here is `(element,index)`).

Comment: I would like to do it with vanilla javascript, but I'm not sure this does what I intend. When the screen is under 768px, I am using GSAP to set the data-speed to a single value like this smoother.effects('.smootherReset768', {speed: 1}); AND when we change the screen size back above 768px, I just would like to reset the data-speed attributes of each element to their original which is in-line in the html

Comment: I am not familiar with GSAP, so: you might well have a reason to use jQuery! I have _loved_ working with it in the past. Don't get me wrong, I still think it is a great library. The above jQuery snippet should provide you with a basis to incorporate your GSAP elements into it.